# Using SimpleXML in PHP with a Twist

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using SimpleXML to load a remote XML

My PHP code looks like below

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.abc.om/xml.php');

foreach( $xml as $Product )
    {
        echo 'ProductCode: '.$Product->ProductCode.'<br />';
        echo 'ProductName: '.$Product->ProductName.'<br />';

    }
```

MY XML looks like below

```
<All_Products>
<Product>
<ProductCode>9978H</ProductCode>
<ProductName>abc with Buckle in aBlack</ProductName>
<StockStatus>2</StockStatus>
</Product>
</All_Products>
```

Product tags are repeated as there are many products

**after reading that XMLfeed the XML feed should display with some ammends that is before 
`<StockStatus>` tag it should add a tag**

```
<ProductURL><ProductURL>
```

and that tag should display like

```
<ProductURL>http://abc.com/abc with Buckle in aBlack-p/9978H.htm<ProductURL>
```

That means each ProductURL should be appended as

```
<ProductURL>http://abc.com/<ProductName>-p/<ProductCode>.htm<ProductURL>
```

The final XML to display will look like

```
<All_Products>
<Product>
<ProductCode>9978H</ProductCode>
<ProductName>abc with Buckle in aBlack</ProductName>
<ProductURL>http://abc.com/abc with Buckle in aBlack-p/9978H.htm<ProductURL>
<StockStatus>2</StockStatus>
</Product>
</All_Products>
```

So my questions are

1) Do i have to read all the elements of the Product tag in the foreach( $xml as $Product ) loop and then append ProductURL element or is there any shortcut to do it

2) Once this data is ready how do i again display the data in XML format

Comment: And your question is? What have you tried? :)

Comment: I see an error: `</<All_Products>`

Comment: @MartinsBriedis sorry updated the code

Comment: @phpdev i added the question i tried reading XML and loading but how to read those 2 specific tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DOM](http://au.php.net/dom) with SimpleXML.

Here's what you should do:

1. Use [xpath()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to run an xpath query that picks out all the `Product` tags. This should return you an array of `SimpleXMLElement`s representing each `Product` tag.
2. Use xpath() again to select from each `Product` tag the `ProductCode` and `ProductName` and get their contents. Create your url and save it to a variable.
3. Use xpath() to select the `StockStatus` tag.
4. Using DOM's [dom_import_simplexml()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php), convert the `SimpleXMLElement` `StockStatus` tags to a `DOMElement`.
5. Create the `ProductURL` element using DOM's [createElement()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and insert the url we created before.
6. Insert it before `StockStatus` using DOM's [insertBefore()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361036/php-simplexml-insert-node-at-certain-position) should show you how to do the conversion to a `DOMElement` and finally do the insertion.

Comment: I tried till step 3 and it works great i did this $element = $dom->createElement('ProductURL', 'This is the root element!');
// We insert the new element as root (child of the document)
$dom->appendChild($element);

but i am not sure how to create that producr url dynamically like <ProductURL>http://abc.com/<ProductName>-p/<ProductCode>.htm<ProductURL>

Comment: your first step doesnt work i tried using the following it doesnt picks out the product tags 

$result = $xml->xpath('/All_Products/Product');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo '/a/b/c: ',$node,"\n";
}