# SimpleXML add element before

Tags: php, xml, xsd, simplexml

I'm using *SimpleXML* to generate xml based invoice.

The structure has to be like this (heavily simplified):

```
<invoice>
    <total>
        <price>100</price>
    </total>
    <items>
        <item>...</item>
    </items>
</invoice>
```

But if first loop my items and add totals together, and then insert `<total>`:

```
<invoice>
    <items>...</items>
    <total>...</total>
</invoice>
```

But **CUSTOM XSD** says it invalid. This probably will not cause an error in applications, but I'd like it to be valid.

So can I insert `<total>` tag *before* `<items>` tag?

**Note:** `<items>` tag is not the first element in `<invoice>`.

Jquery equivalent of the function in need is *[.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)*

Cheers!

Comment: Your second example seems valid. I suspect it is the nodes that you have substituted with ellipses that are the source of the problem.

Comment: I have custom XSD file, which requires `<total>` to be before `<items>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    $domelement = dom_import_simplexml($items);

    $new = $dom->insertBefore(
        $dom->ownerDocument->createElement("total"),
        $dom->firstChild
    );

    $newsxml = simplexml_import_dom($new);
```

then add the items into total node.

Comment: Yes found it just on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361036/php-simplexml-insert-node-at-certain-position. Thanks anyways! :)