# Insert XML structure as a child of another XML Element using PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Is it possible to insert a PHP `SimpleXMLElement` as a child of another Element

```
$xml   = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
$xml_a = new SimpleXMLElement('<parent/>');
$xml_b = new SimpleXMLElement('<child/>');
$xml_b->addAttribute('attribute','value');
$xml_b->addChild('item','itemValue');
// the part will cause and error
$xml_a->addChild($xml_b);
$xml->addChild($xml_a);
```

I know the above code doesn't work, but that would be the sort of thing I'm looking for.

So that the structure looks like:

```
<root>
 <partent>
  <child attribute="value">
   <item>itemValue</item>
  </child>
 </parent>
</root>
```

I have tried using something like the below to `addChild()`  :

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml_a);
$_xml_ = $dom->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom->ownerDocument->documentElement);
$xml->addChild('parent',$_xml_);
```

The solution im sure is relatively simple, but I've not used `SimpleXMLElement` like this before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP SimpleXML: insert node at certain position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361036/php-simplexml-insert-node-at-certain-position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with SimpleXML, but if you really need manipulate your DOM or create it from scratch consider DOMDocument.

```
$xmlObject   = new \DOMDocument();
$xml = $xmlObject->createElement('root');
$xml_a = $xmlObject->createElement('parent');
$xml_b = $xmlObject->createElement('child');
$xml_b->setAttribute('attribute','value');
$xml_b->appendChild(new \DOMElement('item', 'itemValue'));
$xml_a->appendChild($xml_b);
$xml->appendChild($xml_a);
$xmlObject->appendChild($xml);
echo $xmlObject->saveXML();
```

Comment: Working like a charm :) one question. The xml header shows as `<?xml version="1.0"?>` can i influence that so as to set the attribute `encoding="UTF-8"`

Comment: Yes,

`$xmlObject   = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`